# Mips DataMemory with Verilog

Tags: verilog, mips, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to make MIPS Data Memory with Verilog.

The code does not work properly. It is unable to read and write as of right now. I thought the code that I made is correct, but if there is any flaw in here, please make it work. The code below is what I made and used.

```
//WORD_LEN = 32
//MEM_CELL_SIZE = 8
//DATA_MEM_SIZE = 1024

module DataMemory(CLK, rst, Addr, WriteData, ReadData, MemRead, MemWrite);

  input CLK, rst;
  input MemRead, MemWrite;  //switch
  input [`WORD_LEN-1:0] Addr, WriteData;
  output reg[`WORD_LEN-1:0] ReadData; 

  reg [`MEM_CELL_SIZE-1:0] DataMem [0:`DATA_MEM_SIZE];
  wire [`WORD_LEN-1:0] Pointer;

  integer i;

  always @(negedge CLK) //Write on memory needs CLK
   begin
    if(rst)
    for (i = 0; i < `DATA_MEM_SIZE; i = i + 1) 
          DataMem[i] <= 0;
    /*
    // Identify each DataMem
    */
    else if(MemWrite == 1 && MemRead == 0) // Store Word
    {DataMem[Pointer], DataMem[Pointer+1], DataMem[Pointer+2], DataMem[Pointer+3]} <= WriteData;


    else if(MemWrite == 0 && MemRead == 1) // Load Word
    ReadData <= ((Addr >= 1024) ? 0 : {DataMem[Pointer], DataMem[Pointer+1], DataMem[Pointer+2], DataMem[Pointer+3]});
    end

  // Pointer must be added 4 shifter >>2 << 2 helps to flush 1~3
    assign Pointer = (Addr >> 2) << 2;

endmodule
```

And Testbench which I use below here.

```
`include "Defines.v"

//WORD_LEN = 32
//MEM_CELL_SIZE = 8
//DATA_MEM_SIZE = 1024

module DataMemoryTest;
  reg CLK, rst;
  reg MemRead, MemWrite;
  reg [`WORD_LEN-1:0] Addr, WriteData;
  wire [`WORD_LEN-1:0]ReadData;

  DataMemory TestDataMemory(.CLK(CLK), .rst(rst), .Addr(Addr), .WriteData(WriteData),
               .ReadData(ReadData), .MemRead(MemRead), .MemWrite(MemWrite));

  initial begin
     CLK = 1;
     repeat(5000) #50 CLK = ~CLK;
  end

  initial begin
    rst = 1;
    #100;

    MemRead = 0;
    MemWrite = 1;
    Addr = 32'd0;
    WriteData = 32'd123;

    #100;

    MemRead = 0;
    MemWrite = 1;
    Addr = 32'd4;
    WriteData = 0;

    #100;

    MemRead = 0;
    MemWrite = 1;
    Addr = 32'd8;
    WriteData = 32'd17;

    #100;

    MemRead = 1;
    MemWrite = 0;
    Addr = 32'd12;
    WriteData = 32'd123;

    #100;

    MemRead = 1;
    MemWrite = 0;
    Addr = 32'd16;
    WriteData = 0;

    #100;

    MemRead = 1;
    MemWrite = 0;
    Addr = 32'd20;
    WriteData = 32'd17;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

The testbench keeps the design in reset. You need to set `rst`=0 after some delay.

```
  initial begin
    rst = 1;
    #500;

    rst = 0;
    #100;

    MemRead = 0;
    MemWrite = 1;
    Addr = 32'd0;
    WriteData = 32'd123;
```